# Turning a string into an integer?

Tags: c++, string, function, int, radix

I'm making a  function that inputs a string class number and translates it into integers.

for example. I punch in 123 I'll get back 123 as an integer, or I punch in 1D2F I...guess I get it back? But I figured I'll turn any base number back to decimal. (But how would I make this string into a decimal if I'm not completely sure you can do math effectively with strings?

So far for my stringToInt function I have.

```
int StringToInt (string inputString){
   int i;
   int newIntegerLine;

      for (i=0; i<inputString.length();i++){
         //subtracts the ascii number of 0 from
         //whatever character you input
         newIntegerLine= (inputString.at(i)- '0');
      }

   return newIntegerLine;
}
```

I figured I can use the ascii numbers to get characters to integers. But when  I run it whatever I put it is returned as 0. And I really am not sure how to approach the base number problem (What to do with A-F, perhaps if statements? Is there a more elegant way of doing this?). Can I call my base function within my StringToInt function? Or is there already a function I can use to accomplish this? Am I just complicating matters?

my base function (Which seems to work I guess? There seems to be a slight issue with binary numbers when I punch in 100 and say its in base 2 I get 24 back as it's decimal equivalent. Otherwise it works perfectly.)

```
int baseToDecimal (int numInput, int base){
   int i, modSum;
   modSum=numInput%10;
   for(i=base;(numInput/=10)!=0;i*=base)
      modSum+=numInput*i;
   return modSum;
   }
```

Comment: What is wrong with std::stoi(string) ?

Comment: Ignorance I suppose. I'm simply unaware of a function called stoi. I'll look it up.

Comment: @ScarletAmaranth I think it's called `atoi` http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdlib/atoi/

Comment: `C++11` I think introduced `stoi`.  Otherwise, you need to convert to a C-String and use `atoi`.

Comment: Another method using existing library code is to use Boost Lexical Cast http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_55_0/doc/html/boost_lexical_cast.html - and under the hood this uses std::stringstream, which you could use directly.

Answer (score 2):

The old C way ([`atoi`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/byte/atoi)):

```
std::string foo = "1337";
int bar = atoi(foo.c_str());
```

Using [`std::istringstream`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_istringstream):

```
std::string foo = "1337";
int bar;
std::istringstream(foo) >> bar;
```

C++11's [`std::stoi`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/stol):

```
std::string foo = "1337";
int bar = std::stoi(foo);
```

which under the hood uses [`std::strtol`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/byte/strtol):

```
std::string foo = "1337";
int bar = std::strtol(foo.str(), nullptr, 10);
```

And to add an example for [@polkadotcadaver](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2428400/polkadotcadaver)'s mention of [`boost::lexical_cast`](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/release/doc/html/boost_lexical_cast.html):

```
std::string foo = "1337";
int bar = boost::lexical_cast<int>(foo);
```

*Don't forget to add appropriate **error handling**!*

Comment: A very very minor point - with lexical_cast there's no need to use .c_str().

Comment: You are right, thanks! Copy-paste from the `std::strtol` example :D